# How can I combine a new action to a pre-existing action in the NLA properly

Tags: animation, nla-editor, mixamo

I am using a mixamo rig / walk cycle and want to have my character take a drag of a cigarette. I created a new action for the cigarette animation but when it combines the action the hand "spazzes out" and wont blend smoothly between the custom action i made and the walk cycle i downloaded. Additionally, I cant use any blend mode besides replace or weird deformations occur. Is this a problem with my mixamo rig? I am using a control rig created with the mixamo addon for blender.

Comment: I don't see how this can be answered very easily without more information. Could you make a file with a stripped-down, minimal failing version of the problem you're having? Illustrate _that_ as clearly as you can, and share the file on https://blend-exchange.com/ ?